# Print somethng rendered like a QRCODE in react native

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, printing, rendering

I'm searching to find a way to print QRCodes i generated with react-native-qrcode-svg, but for now it look impossible and didn't find any way to do it.
I've founded only one but this solution was with expo and i'm working on android studio.
Anybody got help ? Thanks

Comment: You want to generate QR codes or scan them?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.